# Define an interface based on existing inline type for a function parameter

Tags: typescript

Lets say that a library has a function of this type

```js
export declare class TheClass {
   get: (getArgs?: { arg1: string, arg2: boolean }): Promise<unknown> 
}
```

I need to get the type of the `getArgs` parameter, but I do not know how to "extract" the type from an inline type of a function parameter like that. Is it even possible?

I could of course just copy the type and define it myself but that's bad for obvious reasons if the lib changes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a bit of [index access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and the built-in [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) conditional type. You can also use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) if you want to remove `undefined` from the type (which will be in there because of the optionality of the parameter):

```
export declare class TheClass {
   get: (getArgs?: { arg1: string, arg2: boolean }) => Promise<unknown> 
}

type Param = Parameters<TheClass['get']>[0]
type ParamNoUndefined = Exclude<Parameters<TheClass['get']>[0], undefined>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDm9BnPOAFQAtgBhDAuAbwCg5GBzYGALjgAoWYBBKJngD8HGnExMAjBzwwoASwB2TADTiBAJg4AjCBFTB0iuAF8AlHAC8APjgAFKBAC28vMAA8AV0UBrRRAB3RVs6Ezo6GABPMGw7THQnK3t4p1ZgKDx3UgoqPABtAHIeAoBdazyABhKI6NiUgDkIAFVFJAAzJWAEJIBREDRPJHc4qAS0jKyySnx8otZS8qq1b3bOhGsgA)